# Square Retrofit repeats network calls

Tags: android, retrofit

I am using the Square's Retrofit library to handle networking for an application. I have noticed that the library makes repeated HTTP calls for no apparent reason and I do not really know why.

I have verified that the call to the interface method is executed only once from the android activity (ie.userAPI.getUserByFacebookIdAsync()).

Has anyone experimented this too? Perhaps has something to do with the OKhttp library setup?

Any help much appreciated.

RETROFIT LOGGING

```
08-18 21:25:56.895  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://server-instance:8080/server-app//user/facebook?facebookId=00000000
08-18 21:25:56.895  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookId: 00000000
08-18 21:25:56.895  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookToken: XXXXX
08-18 21:25:56.895  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)

08-18 21:25:57.434  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://server-instance:8080/server-app//user/facebook?facebookId=00000000
08-18 21:25:57.434  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookId: 00000000
08-18 21:25:57.434  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookToken: XXXXX
08-18 21:25:57.434  30331-30372/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)

08-18 21:25:57.441  30331-30359/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> HTTP GET http://server-instance:8080/server-app/user/facebook?facebookId=00000000
08-18 21:25:57.441  30331-30359/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookId: 00000000
08-18 21:25:57.441  30331-30359/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ FacebookToken: XXXXX
08-18 21:25:57.441  30331-30359/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ ---> END HTTP (no body)

08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ <--- HTTP 200 http://server-instance:8080/server-app/user/facebook?facebookId=00000000 (770ms)
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ : HTTP/1.1 200 OK
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ Content-Type: application/json
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ Date: Tue, 19 Aug 2014 02:05:59 GMT
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Received-Millis: 1408413959446
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Response-Source: CONDITIONAL_CACHE 200
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Selected-Protocol: http/1.1
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ OkHttp-Sent-Millis: 1408413959001
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
08-19 03:05:59.448  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ Transfer-Encoding: chunked
08-19 03:05:59.456  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ {"id":4,"facebookId":"00000000","gender":"male","city":"Barcelona","country":"Spain","firstName":"John","premium":false}
08-19 03:05:59.456  10069-10345/com.package.name D/Retrofit﹕ <--- END HTTP (390-byte body)
```

The responses to the extra 2 calls are received too, they are simply not included in the logging sample.

NETWORK CALL (ACTIVITY CODE INCLUDED FURTHER BELOW)

```
userAPI.getUserByFacebookIdAsync(user.getId(), new Callback<User>() {
    @Override
    public void success(User user, Response response) {}
    @Override
    public void failure(RetrofitError error) {}
```

RETROFIT API INTERFACE METHOD

```
@GET("/user/facebook")
void getUserByFacebookIdAsync(@Query("facebookId") String facebookId, Callback<User> cb);
```

RETROFIT API HANDLER

```
public class APIHandler {
static RequestInterceptor requestInterceptor = new RequestInterceptor() {
    @Override
    public void intercept(RequestFacade request) {
        request.addHeader("FacebookId", Constants.FACEBOOK_ID);
        request.addHeader("FacebookToken", Constants.FACEBOOK_TOKEN);
    }
};
private static RestAdapter restAdapter;

private static RestAdapter getRestAdapter() {
    if (restAdapter == null) {
        restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder().
                setRequestInterceptor(requestInterceptor).
                setLogLevel(RestAdapter.LogLevel.FULL).
                setClient(Constants.OK_CLIENT).
                setEndpoint(BaseAPI.getInstance().BASE_URL).build();
    }
    return restAdapter;
}

public static UserAPI getUserAPI() {
    UserAPI userAPI = null;
    try {
        if (restAdapter == null) {
            restAdapter = getRestAdapter();
        }
        userAPI = restAdapter.create(UserAPI.class);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return userAPI;
}}
```

OKHTTP SETUP (ON APP STARTUP)

```
int cacheSize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MiB
File cacheDirectory = new File(getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath(), "HttpCache");
Cache cache = null;
try {
    cache = new Cache(cacheDirectory, cacheSize);
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
okHttpClient.setCache(cache);
Constants.OK_CLIENT = new OkClient(okHttpClient);
```

ANDROID ACTIVITY

```
public class CurrentUserProfileActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.current_user_profile_activity_layout);

    userAPI = APIHandler.getUserAPI();
    clubAPI = APIHandler.getClubAPI();
    visitAPI = APIHandler.getVisitAPI();

    picasso = PabloPicasso.withDebug(this);

    userProfilePicture = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userProfilePicture);

    makeMeRequest(Session.getActiveSession());

    userProfilePicture.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), PictureViewerActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("facebookId", mUser.getFacebookId());
            startActivity(intent);
            return false;
        }
    });
    }

    private void makeMeRequest(final Session session) {
       Request request = Request.newMeRequest(session,
            new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, com.facebook.Response response) {
                    // If the response is successful
                    if (session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                        if (user != null) {
                            userAPI.getUserByFacebookIdAsync(user.getId(), new Callback<User>() {
                                @Override
                                public void success(User user, Response response) {
                                    mUser = user;
                               }
                                @Override
                                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                                    Log.d(TAG, "userApi call to get User object from server failed!");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                    if (response.getError() != null) {
                        Intent introActivityIntent = new Intent(CurrentUserProfileActivity.this, IntroActivity.class);
                        introActivityIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                        startActivity(introActivityIntent);
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
       );
       request.executeAsync();
    }}
```

Comment: are you using Otto or some other eventbus as well?

Comment: Not the case @nPn. I do use Retrofit, OKhttp and Picasso as networking libraries. I added some extra code that may be relevant. Thanks for replying!

Comment: Any solution to this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a post on Medium about, explains everything

https://medium.com/inloop/okhttp-is-quietly-retrying-requests-is-your-api-ready-19489ef35ace#.mj80t78ir

> You can only disable request retrying globally for the whole `OkHttpClient` instance. This is done by using the `OkHttpClient.Builder` and setting `retryOnConnectionFailure` to false.